# How to detect object position in image in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm a newbie in Tensorflow, and looking to the sample object detection codes. One of these is [that](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/blob/master/Object_detection_image.py)

I just don't know how can I get the exact coordinates(position) of detected array in image for this sample codes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact answer: 
[Get the bounding box coordinates in the TensorFlow object detection API tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915003/get-the-bounding-box-coordinates-in-the-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial)

After this:

```
out = vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
image,
np.squeeze(boxes),
np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
np.squeeze(scores),
category_index,
use_normalized_coordinates=True,
line_thickness=1,
min_score_thresh=0.80)
```

Position is:

```
im_height, im_width = image.shape[:2]

position = boxes[0][0]

(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) = (position[1]*im_width, position[3]*im_width, position[0]*im_height, position[2]*im_height)

roi = image2[int(ymin):int(ymax), int(xmin):int(xmax)]
```

Thanks [rootkitchao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10420733/rootkitchao)

Answer (score 1):

```
# Run the model
    out = sess.run([sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0'),
                    sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0'),
                    sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0'),
                    sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')],
                   feed_dict={'image_tensor:0': inp.reshape(1, inp.shape[0], inp.shape[1], 3)})

     # Visualize detected bounding boxes.
    num_detections = int(out[0][0])
    for i in range(num_detections):
        classId = int(out[3][0][i])
        score = float(out[1][0][i])
        bbox = [float(v) for v in out[2][0][i]]
```

Comment: I've done it as you said. But when I print bbox it return this: [0.2702380418777466, 0.4774879515171051, 0.6260198354721069, 1.0]. Are they coordinates?

Comment: They are relative coordinates.If you want to get absolute coordinates, use the following code.x = bbox[1] * cols
            y = bbox[0] * rows
            right = bbox[3] * cols
            bottom = bbox[2] * rows

Comment: Do you mean: x is x1; y is y1; right is x2; bottom is y2; cols is image_width and rows is image_height?